Upgraded Angular 16 application is generating errors
I have an Angular 10 application that I tried to update and make it use Angular 16. I followed the Angular Update Guide page and went up, one version at a time. It all went smooth until I tried moving from Angular 15 to Angular 16. Now, when I execute the "ng version" command in my Visual Studio Code terminal, I see this:
Angular CLI: 16.2.14
Node: 16.20.2
Package Manager: npm 8.19.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.14 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.14 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.14 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    16.2.14 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             16.2.14 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.8.1 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
zone.js                         <error>

Why are there so many errors listed?
The "ng build" command generates this quick error:
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser' builder's node package.

Running "npm install" generates this error, after it goes through the process for a while:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:857
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild --version
npm ERR! node:child_process:899
npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe UNKNOWN
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1119:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:847:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:890:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:220:28)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
npm ERR!   errno: -4094,
npm ERR!   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync C:\\Projects\\DevSystems\\MMWA\\Source\\UI\\TabletApp\\tablet-app\\node_modules\\@esbuild\\win32-x64\\esbuild.exe',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Projects\\DevSystems\\MMWA\\Source\\UI\\TabletApp\\tablet-app\\node_modules\\@esbuild\\win32-x64\\esbuild.exe',
npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
npm ERR!   status: null,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: null,
npm ERR!   pid: 0,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:861:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:896:15)
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:98:28)
npm ERR!     at C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:283:5 {
npm ERR!   status: 1,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: [
npm ERR!     null,
npm ERR!     Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm ERR!     Buffer(1377) [Uint8Array] [
npm ERR!       110, 111, 100, 101,  58,  99, 104, 105, 108, 100,  95, 112,
npm ERR!       114, 111,  99, 101, 115, 115,  58,  56,  57,  57,  13,  10,
npm ERR!        32,  32,  32,  32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119,  32, 101, 114,
npm ERR!        10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,
PS C:\Projects\DevSystems\MMWA\Source\UI\TabletApp\tablet-app> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: panynj-tablet-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project  
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.14     
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\el\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\el\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-01T00_37_05_023Z-debug-0.log

Any thoughts?
Ed
Edit: I'll use edits to post comments and address some of the suggestions you have made.
For Tibere, issueing that command gives this error:
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 0 dependencies.
Package '@angular-devkit/build-angular' is not a dependency.

For Yassin, I removed the contents of the node_modules folder and issued the 'npm install' command. It generates an error that has been shown above:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: panynj-tablet-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.14 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\elascu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\el\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-01T14_44_39_506Z-debug-0.log

I do have angular-devkit listed as a dependency:
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",

Problem may arise from the fact that in the package-lock.json file I have the old one that did not get migrated:
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.11",

I also cleaned the npm cache several times, but that did not help.

Try deleteing node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Hi NF - I've added some more details to the ticket in the Edit section. Deleting the content of the node_modules and re-running the "npm install" command did not help.

I have encountered this error before, try to follow one of these steps:
1- Reinstall Dependencies:
remove 'node_modules' directory and reinstalling dependencies by running:
npm install

2- Update Angular CLI:
If you've recently updated your Angular version, ensure that you've updated Angular CLI as well by running:
npm install -g @angular/cli

3- Verify @angular-devkit/build-angular:
ensure that the @angular-devkit/build-angular package is listed as a dependency in package.json file. If it's missing, you can add it manually by running:
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --save

4- Clear Cache:
Sometimes, caching issues can cause this problem, use this command:
npm cache clean --force


Yassin - See the additional details provided as edits in the original post. Thanks for trying to help

From what I can see from your npm error, you seems to have a discrepancy with the installed version of angular-devkit/build-angular which is still in version 15.
I'd suggest running the following command
ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular@16

And then check for any more errors.

Tibere B. - See the additional details provided as edits in the original post. Thanks for trying to help

You can try to specifically update the @angular-devkit/build-angular with npm :
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@16
